# Initilize a property object

Tags: c#

I have properties such as

```
public class TeleServerTest
{
    public TelephonyServer TServer { get; set; }
    public ChannelResource CResource { get; set; }
```

In the constructor

```
    public TeleServerTest(TelephonyServer telephonyServer)
    {
        TServer = telephonyServer;
        CResource = TServer.GetChannel();
```

To call TeleServerTest is from another class

```
public static TelephonyServer MessagingTelephonyServer { get; set; }
 .....
MessagingTelephonyServer = new TelephonyServer(sIpaddress, "username", "password");
TeleServerTest test= new TeleServerTest(MessagingTelephonyServer);
```

I am little confused by the initialize the object. Do we have to define it first

```
CResource =  new ChannelResource();
```

Then in the constructor

```
CResource = TServer.GetChannel();
```

My original code does have the initialization of CResource.

Comment: It depends on what is in `GetChannel()`.  If that handles the creation *and/or* retrieval of a `ChannelResource` then you should be able to just do `CResource = TServer.GetChannel();`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If `TServer.GetChannel()` returns a `ChannelResource`  then you don't need to initialize it like this:

```
CResource =  new ChannelResource();
```

Also you might want to make sure that `telephonyServer` is not *null* before calling the `TServer.GetChannel();`

Comment: I used the third party tools, not sure it. Please see http://help.voiceelements.com/html/M_VoiceElements_Client_TelephonyServer_GetChannel.htm

Comment: @Love it looks like it returns a `ChannelResource`.So it's okey to initialize it by calling the `GetChannel` method.

Answer (score 1):

> I am little confused by the initialize the object. Do we have to
>   define it first?

`CResource` is already defined as a property.

```
public ChannelResource CResource { get; set; }
```

> Then in the constructor `CResource = TServer.GetChannel();`

It is not a constructor call, it is calling an instance method of `TelephonyServer` which is returning an object of type `ChannelResource`, which gets assigned to the `CResource` property.

Constructor call to ChannelResource `CResource =  new ChannelResource();` is probably made in `TServer.GetChannel();` that is why you don't need the initialization in your code.